# ModRewrite Redirect Loop

Tags: .htaccess

Basically I have this code on my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(login.php|signup.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^(login.php|signup.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It was supposed to send the user to a SSL Connection. But it keeps having a redirect loop. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use back-references with negative patterns. Try `%{REQUEST_URI}`. `RewriteRule !^(login\.php|signup\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: @Deadooshka: That's a very valid point, post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use back-references with negative patterns.

```
RewriteRule !^login\.php$|^signup\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

or this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !login\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !signup\.php$
RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Stil getting the Redirect Loop... :( Any other ideas what may be causing it?

Comment: @NiltonFredericoTeixeira May be negative patterns not allow parentheses. `!^login\.php$|^signup\.php$`

Comment: Now the redirect loop occours only in the login and signup.php pages. We're getting somewhere, thanks, there is some mistake in this line:

    `RewriteRule ^(login.php|signup.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]` ?

Comment: @NiltonFredericoTeixeira edited. negative patterns in mod_rewrite not documented, so we have many variants to test.

Comment: @NiltonFredericoTeixeira: Test in a new browser.

Comment: Tested the new code, and in a new browser. Nothing yet. Now I'm reaching the index page. Any ideas? (Sorry guys for troubling you)

Comment: @NiltonFredericoTeixeira check if `%{HTTPS}` not defined. Append it to the url as the parameter `https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?%{HTTPS}`. It must be ?on or ?off